# Full window onClick handler in Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, events, internet-explorer

I would like an event handler to fire whenever someone clicks anywhere on a window (so I can clear away a menu if they click someplace other than the menu). The following works in [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29):

```
   function checkwho(ev) {
      obj=(window.external) ? event.srcElement : ev.target;
      var type=obj.nodeName;
      if ((type == 'BODY') || (type == 'HTML') || (type == 'DIV')) clearmenus(); 
   }

   self.onclick=checkwho;
```

But it does not work in Firefox or Internet Explorer 6, i.e. the handler does not get invoked. How to make this work in Firefox and Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

For what it may help, the following works in IE7+, Safari, Firefox and Chrome:

```
<body onclick="clearmenus();">
```

... or "programmatically":

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].onclick = function(){ clearmenus(); };
```

Comment: What about clicks on the menu itself?

Comment: The `clearmenus()` function will get invoked as well. There must be some logic in `clearmenus()` to not clear the menus if the click was on top of a menu.

Comment: As fsb suggested, to avoid these complications, a JavaScript library like jQuery would simplify everything.

Comment: The problem with this is that this only works if you click on the body, which may only cover *part* of the browser window. I'd like the clearmenu function to get invoked if you click *anywhere* in the window (other than the menu itself).

Comment: @Mark: If the body is 100% wide, doesn't it cover the full window?

Comment: no - the body in that case covers the full horizontal extent of the window, but not the full vertical extent, i.e. the body could end partway down the window.

Comment: @Mark: Yes, you're right. The body might end half way into the window.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) makes this kind of problem very easy to solve in a cross-browser manner.

Bind an onclick event handler to body that hides the menu and another to the menu element that stops propagation of the event.

Comment: To illustrate, you'd need a `$('*').live ('click', clearmenus)` and a `$('#menu').live ('click', function (e) { e.stopPropogation(); } )`

Comment: So quick to point to jQuery, there's so many easy ways to make this happen without having deviate from real man's JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script some time ago to [Determine if any "Outside" Element was Clicked with JavaScript](http://blog.josh420.com/archives/2007/11/determine-if-any-other-outside-element-was-clicked-with-javascript.aspx).

Comment: Perfect - the Firefox fix someone made on your blog is what I needed - thanks.

Answer (score -1):

A better option for hiding a menu like that would be to use the `onblur` event.

```
<div id="menu-div" onclick="showMenu('menu');" onblur="hideMenu('menu');">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>Thing1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function showMenu(id)
{
    var me = document.getElementById(id);
    me.style.display = 'block';
}

function hideMenu(id)
{
    var me = document.getElementById(id);
    me.style.display = 'none';
}
```